# Show multishipping order details to only one order detail

Tags: magento2, php, sales-order

When we do multishipping order, there will be multiple orders created, could i made it only one order, but there are multiple order inside? I already tried to made only one order, and i saved the multiple orders to my custom table so i could get the orders. But i can't made the orders show inside only one order detail. Check the picture below for more explaination.

Order Detail :
[image: detail 1]
[image: detail 2]

So, what i mean is, if i do shipping with 2 addresses, there will be 2 details inside 1 order detail (content inside the red line in pictures). Can i do that?